# Block tempmail in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to block temp mail when registering on my site. I try this:

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

    $tempmail = array("@4tmail.com", "@mail3.top", "@mail3plus.net", "@mailfile.org", "@themail3.net", "@mail3tech.com", "@tmailer.org", "@mail3x.net", "@tmails.top", "@tmail2.com");

    $iftmp = strpos($email, $tempmail);
    if ($iftmp == true){
        die("Bad Email");
    }
```

but don't work

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976706/how-to-block-disposable-email-addresses-in-your-websites-registration-form

Comment: `if ( preg_match( '/' . implode('|', $tempmail) . '$/i', strtolower($email)) ) { die('bad email'); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function *in_array* instead of *strpos*

```
$iftmp = in_array($email, $tempmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array because `in_array` search an string in array however the `strpos` search an string in an string.

---

`in_array` take two parameter one that you are finding and second the array.

```
<?php
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

if (in_array("Glenn", $people))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }

?>
```